# PDO multi insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a working insert for a single input field but when I try to add a couple more it seems to break everything. I have a database connection working fine and including that correctly at the top of the page when I change the "isset" to have the 3 columns it breaks.

This is my set statement;

```
if(isset($_POST['title, question, tags']))
{
$success = insertData('questions', 'title', $_POST['title']);
$success = insertData('questions', 'question', $_POST['question']);
$success = insertData('questions', 'tags', $_POST['tags']);
if(!$success)
    echo 'Sorry failed :(';
}
```

The function I call from a functions php file;

```
function insertData($tablename, $columnName, $value)
{
$sql = 'INSERT into '.$tablename.'('.$columnName.') VALUES(:Value)';
$mysqlConnection = getConnection();
$statement = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":Value", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$bReturn = false;

try
{
    $statement->execute();
    $bReturn = true;
}
catch(PDOExecption $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
return $bReturn;
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: This approach doesn't make sense, what if the first 2 are fails and the last one is successful? You will not echo anything because you overwrite the success variable. Also how do you design your database? Must all columns be a part of the same row or what? If yes then this approach will create 3 different rows, is that what you want? Finally, when you say "break everything" what do you mean? Is there an error?

Comment: Hi, I'll try answer your question(s) as best I can.

I'm unsure about the success of each variable I guess I don't want it to post unless all 3 are set.

I got it to work but as you stated it creates each of the three elements on three different rows your quite right there.

All columns are part of the same row, and thats how they need to be submitted. I don't get any errors on the page it just won't load.

Comment: Your method will create 3 rows instead of 1, make a function that accepts all the arguments and creates a single row with them. Check your developer tools, it will probably tell you why the page isn't loading.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['title, question, tags']))
```

Is not correct syntax

instead You can do:

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_POST['tags']))
```

or even

```
if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['tags']))
```

---

It would be easier to do execute it without binding:

**insertData**

```
function insertData($tablename, $params){
//build query string
$column_string = implode(',', array_keys($params));
$value_string = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));
$sql_string = "INSERT INTO {$tablename} ({$columnString}) VALUES ({$value_string})";
//prepare query
$mysqlConnection = getConnection();
$statement = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql_string);

//execute query
$success = $statement->execute(array_values($params));

//return boolean success
return $success;
}
```

But If you really need to bind, you can do it the following way:

```
function insertDataBind($tablename, $params){
//build query string
$column_string = implode(',', array_keys($params));
$value_string = implode(',:', array_keys($params));
$sql_string = "INSERT INTO {$tablename} ({$column_string}) VALUES (:{$value_string})";
//prepare query
$mysqlConnection = getConnection();
$statement = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);
//bind 
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $statement->bindValue($key, $value);
    }
//execute query
$success = $statement->execute();

//return boolean success
return $success;
}
```

**usage:**

```
if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['tags'])){

$params = array('title' => $_POST['title'],
                'question'=>$_POST['question'],
                'tags'=>$_POST['tags']
                );

$success = insertData('questions', $params);

if(!$success)
    echo 'Sorry failed :(';
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate the 'insert data' to ensure that it inserts in the same row and not over 3?

Comment: @user3763859 I expanded on my answer